# Python graphics animation libraries

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a simulation setup and it generates 2D graphs from sound files. I want to write a visualization tool for my simulations. Just like in an audio editing application, I want to play the sound file and see a vertical bar moving on the 2D graph associated with the sound file I am playing.

I am currently using `matplotlib` for my plots but they are all static. Can I do this kind of interactive animation with `matplotlib`?

Is there any other library you can recommend? I can program in C/C++ and Python.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: I could not do it using matplotlib. I wrote my own graphics library using opengl. matplotlib always blocks, non-blocking methods are not cross-platform I guess.

Comment: matplotlib does not block unless you tell it to

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to update existing `matplotlib` plots.  All most all of the artists have `update_*` functions which will modify the data used by the graph, and the graph will reflect the updated data after a call to `draw()`.

A lot of this has already been written and is nicely wrapped up in the [animation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) module, and there is a very nice [tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.com/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).

If you already have a framework you want to shove this into, you need do to something like:

```
ln, = ax.plot(...)
canv = ax.figure.canvas
# some code 
while True:
    # code
    ln.set_xdata(new_x)
    ln.set_ydata(new_y)
    canv.draw()
    # code
```